# Disable autoplay and show controls with HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML5 video which works, but the problem that I have is that whenever I go to the video in the browser - it starts playing immediately. How can I disable the autoplay function? I've tried it with the attribute `autoplay="false"`, but no results.

And the controls is always hidden and I must right click and click on "show controls" for the controls to popup. I also tried enabling this with: `showcontrols="true"`, but no reaction there too.

All help is appreciated. Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>hls.js</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .hlsjs {
                position: relative;
                width: 70%;
            }
            .ratio {
                position: absolute;
                padding-top: 75%;
            }
            video {
                background-color: #ccc;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                if (Hls.isSupported()) {
                    var video1 = document.getElementById("video1");
                    hls1 = new Hls({
                        debug : true
                    }), hls1.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function() {
                        hls1.loadSource("http://fdfasd.com/fdsa.m3u8");
                    });
                    hls1.attachMedia(video1);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hls.js</h1>
        <h2>First instance</h2>
        <div class="hlsjs">
            <video id="video1" autoplay="false" showcontrols="true"></video>
            <div class="ratio"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, if you specify the `autoplay` attribute the video will play automatically, even if it's false. Which can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/whjLf2b6/ - And I think `showcontrols` attribute should actually be `controls`.

Answer (score 9):

If you specify the `autoplay` attribute the video will play automatically, even if it's false. Which can be seen here:

```html
<video src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" autoplay="false"></video>
```

Also, the `showcontrols` attribute should actually be `controls`.

So the desired HTML will be:

```
<video id="video1" controls></video>
```

---

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: On some devices, the video will only autoplay if the volume is set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it completely. The tag attribute doesn't take a boolean but is a switch itself. This will remove autoplay but still show controls

```html
<video
  id="video1" 
  controls 
  src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Show controls is not the correct attribute name. See my earlier answer.

Comment: @evolutionxbox oops, copied original code from question. fixed

Answer (score 1):

Indeed setting `autoplay` to `false` doesn't help some videos will play anyway. See [this case in fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/evuhgfnb/)

You might want to do by code something in the line of if you want to pause all the videos:

```
videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); 
for(video of videos) {
  video.pause(); 
  video.controls = true
}
```

Of course the above case will not work if the `video` tag is in a shadow root element, but then hardly any general solution will work with shadow roots elements. There you will need a custom approach and expand first the shadow roots.